# MethodAccessException with Firebase Analytics when building for mobile from Unity

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

> MethodAccessException: Method `Google.Logger..ctor()' is inaccessible from method` Firebase.Editor.CategoryLogger..ctor(string)'
> Firebase.Editor.CategoryLogger..ctor (System.String category)

I'm trying to integrate Firebase.Analytics. I'm able to build and run in Unity editor, but I get this exception with firebase 6.8.1 (and 6.11.1) when I try to build and run for Android or iOS.  I'm not able to get the latest version (6.16.1) to build and run in the Editor. I've tried contacting Google directly, but I'm still waiting for a response days later.

I'm using Unity 2019.3.0f6, XCode 12.1 and .NET 4.x. In my project I'm also using Google Ads and Flurry sdk.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google's new External Dependency Manager was supposed to replace Play Services Resolver, but I had both in my project and so I deleted Play Services Resolver and Imported the latest version of External Dependency Manager. This allowed EDM to function, and it migrated Firebase Analytics to use Package Manager. Now I'm able to build and run on device.

I believe PlayServicesResolver was meant to be deleted by the importer but I had moved it into my 'Plugins' folder so it wasn't found.